# How can I write this webstorage javascript code without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-storage

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to rewrite this code in javascript without using the jQuery. Is it possible to do that? How can I start? Isn't jQuery javascript as well?

```
var Contacts = {
                index: window.localStorage.getItem("Contacts:index"),
                $table: document.getElementById("table"),
                $form: document.getElementById("form"),
                $button_save: document.getElementById("save"),
                $button_discard: document.getElementById("discard"),


                init: function() {
                    // initialize storage index
                    if (!Contacts.index) {
                        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:index", Contacts.index = 1);
                    }

                    // initialize form
                    Contacts.$form.reset();
                    Contacts.$button_discard.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                        Contacts.$form.reset();
                        Contacts.$form.id_entry.value = 0;
                    }, true);
                    Contacts.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
                        var entry = {
                            id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
                            first_name: this.first_name.value,
                            last_name: this.last_name.value,
                            email: this.standing.value
                        };
                        if (entry.id == 0) { // add
                            Contacts.storeAdd(entry);
                            Contacts.tableAdd(entry);
                        }
                        else { // edit
                            Contacts.storeEdit(entry);
                            Contacts.tableEdit(entry);
                        }

                        this.reset();
                        this.id_entry.value = 0;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }, true);
```

Comment: jQuery IS javascript so of course it can be done.

Comment: jQuery is a set of methods and variables that, yes, are all written in javascript. It is not magic.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to use jQuery.

Comment: You should try to at least add some conditional before `addEventListener` so that it would work in IE with `attachEvent`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do everything done in jQuery without the jQuery-framework. jQuery is actually just a big collection of javascript functions that does a lot of the repetitive tasks for you.

I don't think there is any jQuery in that code. But if I'm mistaken then I would recommend you to use jQuery instead of removing the jQuery dependency from that code unless there is some special reason not to use it (performance or similar).

Comment: Well the $ shows the implementation of jQuery. I'm doing this for my class, my teacher hates jQuery, he says it just makes apps slower, and its nothing but a junk of codes. I need to figure out how to write this in simple javascript

Comment: @user1683471 `$form` is just a property name.  It doesn't refer to jQuery in any way.  `$` is just a variable used an as alias for `jQuery` to save typing.  You could just as easily say `var $ = 5;` but that doesn't mean you are using jQuery.